# Retrieve Facebook users information by date

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the following query to retrieve a particular Facebook users wall information:
https://graph.facebook.com/MY_USER_ID/feed?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN

Now from the above query, I need to list information which are after a particular updated_time. I am having the date in UTC format. say, 1333620660

Can you please suggest how to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter feeds by using `since` parameter.

https://graph.facebook.com/MY_USER_ID/feed?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&since=1333620660

**Edit (after comment):**
Same way, you can use `until` parameter

https://graph.facebook.com/MY_USER_ID/feed?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&since=1333620660&until=1333620890

Refer (the paging section):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Actually we have two time name updated_time and created_time. Is there any way by which I can filter information by updated_time alone

Comment: By two time, if you mean you need to fetch between two times, I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Please review and suggest your thoughts on the following scenario.

Today morning around 10 A.M. (I.S.T) I have posted a comment for a picture.
Now, I am trying to fetch information which are posted between 9A.M to 11A.M using
https://graph.facebook.com/MY_USER_ID/feed?access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN&since=1334048400&until=1334055600

But, 
I receive 

    {
    data: [ ]
    }

as a response. 

I am using the UTC retrieved from http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Comment: Facebook uses GMT time. That is GMT 0. And IST is GMT + 05:30, may be this is cause problem.I would suggest you to call all feeds (without filtering and see the `created_time` of the one you posted. Take UNIX timestamp from there.

Comment: And also, I found that the query parameter SINCE and UNTIL filters the information only based on my posts created_time. Is there any way so that I can filter information by updated_time. (created_time has my photo uploaded time and updated_time contains the comments and liked time values). Can you please suggest how to filter feed by updated_time?

Comment: No, I dont know (I dont think there is one) any filters on updated_time. `since` and `until` are filters for `created_time`. Also, if my answer helped you, mark it as answer.